# Importing all wall posts into custom tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am trying to import all wall posts on a given Fan Page  into a custom welcome tab.

I can't find the FBML for that anywhere although I have to believe it's simple.

Comment: dont use FBML - [it is being depricated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)... That means it will stop working soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can [develop your own tab application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) that does this or alliteratively you can find one that someone else has done :P.  You can [start your search here](https://www.facebook.com/search.php?q=custom%20wall&init=quick&tas=0.32576717669144273&type=apps).  I just searched for "custom wall" and it gave me a few results.  I'm sure one of them will be able to answer your requirements.
Good luck!